# Best Approach to Parse ByteArray or ByteBuffer in Java

Tags: java

I have a ByteArray /Bytebuffer  contains a information about a record ( with different datatypes).  What would be the best approach to parse them into individual fields.

Example :   Record size is  100 bytes
                  Field 1 is  Integer 
                  Field 2 is  Timestamp 
                  Field 3 is  Short Integer
                  Field 4 is  $ Amount in  Decimal
                  Field 5 is  String (remaining bytes )

Answer (score 0):

- For the byte array: wrap it in a `ByteArrayInputStream` and wrap that in a `DataInputStream.` *Or* wrap it in a `ByteBuffer` and proceed as below.
- For the `ByteBuffer:` just use its API directly.